# Does OpenCL always zero-initialize device memory?

Tags: opencl

I've noticed that often, `global` and `constant` device memory is initialized to 0.  Is this a universal rule?  I wasn't able to find anything in the [standard](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf).

Comment: It's probably initialized to zero on a PC because PCs often contain sensitive or confidential information. On a console there would likely not be such a concern.

Comment: My nbody simulator was exploding before a velocity resetter was there.

Comment: CaptainObvious answer is true. It is not specified in the standard. Each device vendor can do this as they want. Zero the memory immediately after allocation will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it doesn't. For instance I had this small kernel to test atomic add:

```
kernel void atomicAdd(volatile global int *result){
    atomic_add(&result[0], 1);
}
```

Calling it with this host code (pyopencl + unittest):

```
def test_atomic_add(self):
    NDRange = (4, 4)
    result = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int32)        
    out_buf = cl.Buffer(self.ctx, self.mf.WRITE_ONLY, size=result.nbytes)
    self.prog.atomicAdd(self.queue, NDRange, NDRange, out_buf)
    cl.enqueue_copy(self.queue, result, out_buf).wait()
    self.assertEqual(result, 16)
```

was always returning the correct value when using my CPU. However on a ATI HD 5450 the returned value was always junk.

And If I well recall, on an NVIDIA the first run was returning the correct value, i.e. 16, but for the following run, the values were 32, 48, etc. It was reusing the same location with the old value still stored there.

When I corrected my host code with this line (copying the 0 value to the buffer):

```
out_buf = cl.Buffer(self.ctx, self.mf.WRITE_ONLY | self.mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=result)
```

Everything worked fine on any devices.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no sentence in standard that states this.
Maybe some driver implementations will do this automatically, but you shoudn't rely on it.

I remember that once I had a case where a buffer was not initialized to 0, but I can't remember the settings of "OS + driver".

Probably what is going on is that the typical OS does not use even 1% of now a days devices memory. So when you start a OpenCL, there is a huge probability that you will fall into an empty zone.

Comment: Interesting reasoning for the answer.  However, the memory is often initialized to 0 on a CPU as well.

Comment: The memory is often not initialized, except on debug mode. However, if you boot up any system, all the memory will be zero. And if not used, will remain like that. And as far as I know GPU memory is rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform that you are developing. As @DarkZeros mentioned in the previous answers, the spec does not imply anything. Please see page 104 of [OpenCL 2.1 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.1.pdf).

However, based on our experience in Mali GPUs, the driver initializes all elements of the newly allocated buffers to zero. This is for the first touch. Later on, as time goes by, and we release this buffer and its memory space is occupied by a new buffer, that memory space is not initialized with zero. *"Again, the first touch sees the zero values. After that, you would see normal gibberish values."*

Hope this helps after such long time!